# Error when creating superuser in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm very new to Python and even newer to Django. I'm using Visual Studio and trying to create a new Django Web Project and receiving the error below:

```
Executing manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gweathersby\documents\Python Experiments\SRC Project Mngr\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\gweathersby\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named SRC Project Mngr.settings
The Python REPL process has exited
```

I've done some searching online and have seen that other folks have had this issue, but to be honest, none of the solutions make sense to me because I'm so new. Could someone advise with simple steps as to how to remedy?

Comment: did you created a virtualenv??

Comment: What steps did you do leading up to this point?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put the settings file in to a folder with spaces in its name. That is no allowed. It has to be a valid Python package name.

Comment: Thanks so much, all, and apologies for my delay. I decided to create my app the more traditional way outside of Visual Studio and have had no problems. Appreciate the responses!